# Keras LSTM learning less than Bag of Words

Tags: python, keras, lstm

A simple bag of words average embedding learns significantly more than a basic LSTM model so I am assuming that I am doing something wrong with the Keras LSTM implementation.  Consider the bag of words (model) and lstm (lstm_model) implementations below:

**Bag of Words**

```
sequence = Input(shape=(_MAXLEN,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(_MAX_FEATURES, _EMBEDDING_DIMS, input_length=_MAXLEN)(sequence)
average = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(embedding)
dense = Dense(100, activation='relu')(average)
preds = Dense(_NUM_LABELS+1, activation='softmax')(dense)

model = Model(report_sequence, preds)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**LSTM**

```
sequence = Input(shape=(_MAXLEN,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(_MAX_FEATURES+1, _EMBEDDING_DIMS, input_length=_MAXLEN, mask_zero=True)(sequence)
lstm_cell = LSTM(100)(embedding)
preds = Dense(_NUM_LABELS+1, activation='softmax')(lstm_cell)
lstm_model = Model(report_sequence, preds)

lstm_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer='adam',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong with my LSTM implementation? I have ~500k examples spread across multiple classes and the bag of words approach quickly approaches reaches 70% accuracy after a single epoch, while the LSTM model is stuck around 17% accuracy after a full epoch and continued to stay there after the second epoch. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: My sequence is actually quite long (say 100+ tokens) so my gut is now telling me that the memory is not propogating all the way to end so I would actually need to either return the state after each word or possibly just use a pre-trained word embedding to try to speed up the learning.

Comment: What's is the max Len...is it over say 300?

Comment: I started with values of around 400 and went down to max len of size 100 and the behavior is still the same. I'm guessing that this is an issue of vanishing gradients because of how long the sequence is?